# Make CSS layout for responsive 3 column DIV grid

Tags: html, css

I need a responsive grid for a 3 column page layout. Of all the suggestions that I have found, none possess all of the requirements. It may be better to start with no CSS example and build from a clean start.

[image]

Requirements:

1. Must be compatible with https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
2. NAV panel is fixed to top of page
3. SIDE columns of fixed with in pixels
4. SIDE columns expand to fill available space to footer
5. FOOTER is fixed at bottom of page
6. TEXT panel expands to fill width, ie: not set to pixel width
7. Must be responsive for mobile phones

The two images above show that only the TEXT panel should expand when the screen is wider.

I do have CSS for the DIV shown above but I have been unable to get the side columns to expand to 100% of the available space no matter what I tried.

```
.header {
    //
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.row.content {
    height: 100%;    
}  
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display: table-cell;    
}
footer {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row.content {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    } 
    .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
        display: flex;      
    }
}

<header>
  <p>Header Text</p>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
  <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
```

No! It is it not a duplicate of another question, because no other question covers all of these requirements. Nor do their answers solve all of the requirements here.

Comment: minimal sample = 'invisible'

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: Have you tried a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **flexbox**. Since you, as mentioned, have to use Bootstrap 3.4 (instead of the flexbox enabled Bootstrap 4.x.x), you will have to write some custom CSS:

```css
.site-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.site-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #222;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.site-footer p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .main>.row {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    background: #efefef;
  }
  
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 300px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="site-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="main container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sidebar sidebar-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">First item</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Third item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content col-xs-12">
        <h2 class="mt-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nulla optio, repudiandae laborum dicta molestias adipisci tempore aspernatur magni fugit corporis aliquid reiciendis, suscipit aut, esse, hic possimus explicabo dolorem!</p>
        <p>Quasi temporibus error, amet consequuntur reprehenderit veniam? Molestiae quos praesentium facilis at repellat iusto maiores porro est, reiciendis, repellendus nam dolores necessitatibus?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nam expedita sint error eos voluptas explicabo, sequi quidem eum, velit vitae autem dolorum vero nulla doloremque beatae enim veritatis ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar sidebar-right col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">First item</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Third item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="site-footer">
    <p class="text-center">&copy; 2019 @My Company</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197795/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-williamk).

Comment: @WilliamK that was because of the `container` class on the `<div class="main container">` div. I have to changed it to `<div class="main container-fluid">`.

Comment: @WilliamK Sure, use media queries to your need: `@media (min-width: <number of pixels> px) css here }`.

Comment: I chose this solution because it used code that already existed throughout the site and will be easier to update.

Comment: I found a bug. The inner content needs text to fill and wrap before the 3-col set expands to 100%. On pages without wrapping text, it doesn't fill the window. You can see the difference here https://artistscope.com/sitemap.asp vs https://artistscope.com/terms.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a pen](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/BXqJbv) where I think I meet all requirements.

It's a classic grid layout with the body being the container with a `min-height: 100vh;` set on it. Every heights are set to auto except for the main content which is 1fr (*one fraction of the available space*).

And I made the header sticky, which can be undone by removing `position: sticky; top: 0;` in the css.

```
body.myContainer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
}
```

The one "trick" i used is setting the `main` to `display: contents;` to put what's inside directly in the grid, though its not really necessary here.
I added the bootsrap stylesheet but it doesn't seems to be interfering.
I also added 2 extra rows of height `auto` and used them to move the asides in if the screen is less than `max-width: 767px`. They will collapse if not used<.

Here is [a second version](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/rXqJdz) with a sticky header and footer.

I used `position: sticky; top: 0;` on the footer and `bottom: 0` on header.

*Note : when using `sticky` it's important to add `position: -webkit-sticky;` for safari support.*

Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/xvyjbb) where I use the first layout with your code.
Boostrap will set some margin, padding, height etc.. so you will have to overwrite them to make it work for you. For example I put the class `myHeader` in the `navbar-wrapper`, removed the `navbar-fixed-top` in the `nav` and in the css :

```
div.myHeader > .container,
div.myHeader > .container .navbar
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I just used the inspector to figure out where to apply those ...

Comment: I did an edit for the first version. Just replaced `100px` by `auto` in `grid-template-rows`

Comment: I see a `flex` wrapper but no grid in your link

Comment: Made a new edit to the post and pens. I now use the body as a grid container

Comment: Added another example with your code this time... What i gave you at first is a general layout... to make it work you need to modify it to your needs and overwrite what need to be overwriten ! If you still can't make it work then this might be another question ;)

Comment: Did another edit explaining : I put the class myHeader in the navbar-wrapper, removed the navbar-fixed-top in the nav ... **but** the burger menu will expend the grid row size which isn't idealistic

Comment: A "fix" to this could be defining a height for the first row (instead of 'auto'), 52px seems what it is anyway. And adding `background-color: black;` to `.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form`

Comment: This solution works well. But it was not chosen because the other solution used code that already existed throughout the site and will be easier to update.